# Why does f.write overwrites a line after an elif statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291387/f-write-keeps-overwritting-lines) but I don't think I was clear enough and it ended up being closed. I am trying to open a file for writing, overwrite if it already exist, write multiple lines based on different conditions by calling `f.write` then close it. I know about using `f = open(path, "a")` for appending but I'd like the file to be overwritten the first time and `a` doesn't do that.

Ideally, If I had something like this, I would get something similar to my desired output which is overwriting a file if it exist and adding lines by calling `f.write`

```
def cell_clicked(self, item):
    if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        name = self.table
        header = name.horizontalHeaderItem(item.column()).text()
        path = '/home/user/file.txt'

        f = open(path, "w")
        if header == "c1":
            f.write('%s\n' % name.item(item.row(), 0).text())
            f.write("In new new line\n")
            # I'd get 2 lines whooo!
    else:
        print('%s' % item.text())
        print (item.row(),item.column())
```

However, what I'm working with is this, it ends up overwriting the file and the lines after the condition changes.

```
def cell_clicked(self, item):
    if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        name = self.table
        header = name.horizontalHeaderItem(item.column()).text()
        path = '/home/user/file.txt'

        f = open(path, "w")
        if header == "c1":
            f.write('%s\n' % name.item(item.row(), 0).text())
        elif header == "c2":
            f.write('%s\n' % name.item(item.row(), 0).text())
            #unfortunately when condition changes and header is equal to c2, it overwrites the previous line
        f.close()

    else:
        print('%s' % item.text())
        print (item.row(),item.column())
```

Comment: Could you strip your code down to a minimal snippet?

Comment: You open the file in `w` mode, deleting everything inside. You write your line. Of course the previous contents are gone; the `elif` had nothing to do with that. Perhaps you were expecting `w` mode not to delete things that were written in the same program execution? Or perhaps you didn't realize you're reopening the file every time you go down this code path?

Comment: Open the file for writing, close it, then open it for appending.

Comment: @user2357112 That's exactly what happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could define a "already written to files" `set` in your `__init__` method:

```
self.__already_written_to = set()
```

Then replace your `open` code by this code:

```
if path in self.__already_written_to:
   mode = "a"
else:
   mode = "w"
   self.__already_written_to.add(path)
with open(path, mode) as f:
    if header == "c1":
        f.write('%s\n' % name.item(item.row(), 0).text())
```

(no need to close the file as it's done automatically when exiting the `with` block)

so first time, the file will be truncated because `path` has never been written to, but the program takes a good note of that by adding `path` to the set.
On next calls, the program remembers that there's something in the file, and appends to it.

I've made it so it can handle several filenames, not only the fixed one that you mentionned in your example, otherwise it's even simpler, and just a boolean class member could act the same.

Comment: In addition, he should be using `with open(path, mode) as f:`.

Comment: never hurts to improve those old constructs, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example closes the file after writing each line; the next call will reopen the file, starting at byte 0 again.

Either resolve the open/close logic, or open the file in *append* mode.

Answer (score 0):

Jean-Francois' answer gave me an idea to do it like this by declaring a boolean `self.isWrittenTo = False` in my **init** then calling it as needed like this

```
if self.isWrittenTo:
    mode = "a"
else:
    mode = "w"
    self.isWrittenTo = True

with open(path, mode)           
    if header == "c1":
        f.write('%s\n' % name.item(item.row(), 0).text())
    elif header == "c2":
        f.write('%s\n' % name.item(item.row(), 0).text())
```